# Meu código não executa por completo

Tags: c

Boa noite, pessoal. Preciso implementar um programa que imprima sempre uma sequência de três números onde não pode haver nenhuma repetição.

Ex.: t = 4.

Output esperado:
(0 1 2)
(0 1 3)
(0 2 3)
(1 2 3)

O programa executa para t = 4, no entanto, para t = 10, ele executa apenas até certo ponto (até i = 6). Já testei cada parte do código e não consigo encontrar o erro, será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigada! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  int v1;
  int v2;
  int v3;
}Triangulo;

int main(){
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);

Triangulo T[n];

int t;
t = (n*(n-1)*(n-2))/6;
printf("t = %d\n", t);

int c = 0;
int f = c+1;
int s = f+1;

for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
  T[i].v1 = c;
  T[i].v2 = f;
  T[i].v3 = s;

if(s != n-1){
  s++;
}else if((s == n-1)&&(f == n-2)){
  c++;
  f = c+1;
  s = f+1;
}else if(s == n-1){
  f++;
  s = f+1;
}
}

for(int j = 0; j < t; j++){
  printf("%d %d %d\n", T[j].v1, T[j].v2, T[j].v3);
}


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar o código completo? No parte que postou não está sendo definido `n`, `T` e `t`. Você deseja só as triplas com valores diferentes ou as permutações? Por exemplo, você quer que tenha `(0 1 2)` e `(2 1 0)` na saída, ou basta `(0 1 2)`?

Comment: Olá. Com o exemplo que você deu, apenas (0 1 2) basta. Vou atualizar o post e colocar o código completo :)

Comment: Você quer todas as permutações que são do tipo `(i j k)` tal que `i < j < k`, correto? Eu deixei uma resposta que faz isso, mas ainda não tenho certeza se é exatamente isso que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer todas as permutações que são do tipo `(i j k)` tal que `i < j < k`, correto? Você não vai conseguir fazer isso usando apenas um `for`. Observe que quando fixamos valores para `i` e `j`, por exemplo, ainda temos os valores de `j+1` até `t-1` para atribuir a `k`. Vejamos um exemplo:

Considere que em determinado momento do algoritmo `i = 1` e `j = 3`, e que `t = 10`. As sequências possíveis fixando esses valores seriam:

```
(1 3 4)
(1 3 5)
(1 3 6)
(1 3 7)
(1 3 8)
(1 3 9)
```

Note que precisamos de um `for` que vai de `j+1` até `t-1` apenas para iterar os possíveis valores de `k`. Da mesma forma, se fixarmos apenas o valor `i`, precisamos de um `for` para percorrer os possíveis valores para `j` e, para cada valor de `j`, um novo `for` para valores de `k`. Acho que já ficou claro que precisamos de um `for` para cada variável.

Segue uma implementação:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int t;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    // Considera todos os valores de 0 até t-1
    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){

        // Considera todos os valores de i+1 até t-1 para impedir que os valores se repitam
        for(int j = i+1; j < t; j++){

            // Considera todos os valores de j+1 até t-1 para impedir que os valores se repitam
            for(int k = j+1; k < t; k++){
                printf("(%d %d %d) ", i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Demonstração [aqui](https://ideone.com/WVObPQ).

Comment: Entendi! Meu problema é que preciso encontrar uma solução em até ordem linear, ou seja, não poderei executar esses 3 loops. Você teria alguma sugestão de como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Então acho que você não precisa imprimir todas as sequências, já que o número de subconjuntos de tamanho `3` em `n` elementos é da ordem de `n^3`, então não dá para imprimir todos em tempo linear. Você pode verificar se é exatamente isso que precisa fazer? É uma questão? Se sim, poderia adicionar o enunciado?

Comment: Então, eu tenho um trabalho para entregar sobre Árvore Geradora Mínima e eu tenho que executar em tempo O(m), onde m é o número de arestas. Eu quero usar esse trecho para gerar subconjuntos de tamanho 3 que seriam vértices de triângulos dentro do meu grafo original. Nesse trecho eu uso o for em função de n, basicamente, então ele acaba ficando maior que o número de arestas e isso, pela especificação, não poderia acontecer.

Comment: Entendi. Existe alguma propriedade particular no grafo de entrada? Não existe algoritmo `O(m)` para o problema da `MST` em grafos arbitrários (ao menos não conheço e não achei nada sobre nas buscas que fiz). Existem algoritmos para a `MST` que são lineares no grafo, isto é `O(m + n)` e é possível achar uma árvore geradora em `O(m)`, mas não a mínima. Também não consegui ver como o algoritmo acima te ajuda com a árvore geradora mínima. Você tá seguindo algum algoritmo específico?

Comment: Na verdade eu estava tentando coisas sem base em nenhum algoritmo, porque minhas buscas também me indicaram isso que você encontrou. Reli a especificação do trabalho e tentarei resolver com caminhos mínimos ao invés de MST's. De toda forma, obrigada pela atenção e pelas respostas!

Comment: Ok. Se puder colocar parte da especificação para tentar te dizer se está indo no caminho correto...

Comment: Então, a professora nos disse que a solução para o trabalho é o algoritmo de Camerini para Minimum Bottleneck Spanning Tree. Você sabe algo a respeito? Estou com dificuldades para interpretar como ele deve ser implementado.

Comment: Tentei fazer uma implementação com Kruskal, mas não consigo fugir do O(m log n).

Comment: Acho que não tem como fugir do `O(m lg n)` usando `Kruskal` (apenas se não ordenasse as arestas, mas aí você não conseguiria garantir nada). O [Algoritmo de Camerini](https://bit.ly/2H73Nac) é realmente o que você precisa. A maior dificuldade é calcular a mediana em `O(n)`, mas você consegue usar o algoritmo [median of medians](https://bit.ly/2gPtxMP), que te devolve uma mediana aproximada, e é suficiente. Fiz uma implementação do `median of medians` em `c`, segue o [link](https://bit.ly/2Jy30Sv). Mais sobre o resto do algoritmo você pode ver [aqui](https://bit.ly/2Hdqqew).

Comment: Para criar a floresta com o subgrafo formado apenas pelas arestas com valor menor que a mediana, basta selecionar essas aresta e aplicar uma [DFS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_em_profundidade). No anterior link tem exemplos de implementações da `DFS`.

Comment: Li o link mas continuo com dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento do algoritmo. Eu não entendo por que essa parte deve ser feita: If the subgraph is connected, V is the upper limit of the answer, and decrease the V, repeat the step 1, 2.
* If the subgraph is not connected, let the connected component to become a node, and increase the V, repeat the step 1, 2.

Comment: Não entendo o motivo dessa condição. A verdade é que ainda não consigo visualizar como o algoritmo deve funcionar, entendi que tenho que calcular a mediana mas não entendo como isso vai ajudar nas outras partes. Enfim, obrigada pelo código de exemplo da median of medians!

Comment: O que o algoritmo faz é dividir as arestas em dois conjuntos: `A` formado pelas menores que a mediana e `B` pelas maiores. Se for possível construir uma árvore geradora usando somente as arestas menores (de `A`), o algoritmo repete o processo considerando apenas as arestas de `A`. Caso não seja possível, o algoritmo pega a maior árvore que  conseguir usando apenas arestas de `A` e considera essa árvore como um vértice e repete o processo agora para o novo grafo. Observe que todas as arestas de `B` são maiores que as de `A`, logo, no segundo caso é sempre seguro pegar arestas de `A`.

Comment: Usando a mediana, a ideia é que os tamanhos de `A` e `B` sejam aproximadamente `m/2`, assim a cada passo o número de arestas do grafo é diminuído pela metade.

Comment: Certo, mas ainda tenho umas perguntas. Pela descrição do TP, o grafo será completo. Nesse caso teria como eu garantir que a árvore formada não tenha ciclos? Outra dúvida é que eu não vou precisar ordenas as arestas para encontrar a mediana, então como eu encontro um bom meio de encontrar esse valor? E eu ainda não entendo muito bem essa questão de considerar a árvore um vértice e uni-la a outra aresta. Que aresta seria essa visto que minhas arestas estariam desordenadas? Vou tentar pegar alguns valores de um dos arquivos de entrada e postar aqui para tentar esclarecer outra dúvida.

Comment: 8615  
11916  
16355  
12755  
15219  
11364  
9739  
13373  
3151  
3500  
8566  
15285  
6617  
16484  
13096  
5947  
11737  
5067  
14165  
3569  
14263  
14288  
2728  
15063  
10913  
3163  
9893  
13660  
3026  
18147  
10743  
8019  
3565  
13810  
10111  
12865  
12077  
3696  
18201  
10430  
11542  
8936  
15773  
7915  
16064

Comment: A resposta para essa entrada é 8615.

Comment: O problema é que quando eu seleciono o valor na posição da mediana, o valor é 2728 que é o meu menor valor, então o lado com arestas de menor valor fica vazio.

Comment: Dado o conjunto `A` de arestas, você precisa escolher um subconjunto `T` de arestas que formam uma árvore. Você não precisa pegar todas as arestas de `A`, basta pegar um subconjunto. Dessa forma você garante que é uma árvore (basta escolher arestas de forma a ser uma árvore). Note que nem sempre você vai conseguir ligar todos os vértices nessa árvore, daí você cai no segundo caso do algoritmo.

Comment: Para pegar a mediana você pode usar o algoritmo `median of medians` que mandei em um comentário anterior, ele vai te dar uma mediana aproximada em `O(n)`. Para a entrada que colocou a saída dele é `12148.50`.  Ao particionar as arestas em menores ou iguais (`A`) e maiores (`B`) usando a mediana devolvida pelo algoritmo, o conjunto `A` teria `27` arestas e o `B` teria `18`. É uma media aproximada, o algoritmo nem sempre vai dividir exatamente na metade, mas vai ficar próximo. [Aqui](https://ideone.com/lXOWSd) o algoritmo calculando a mediana para a entrada que você colocou.

Comment: Sobre considerar a árvore como um único nó. Note que no final você precisa devolver uma árvore geradora (isto é, uma árvore que conecta todos os vértices), logo, se você já tem uma árvore `T` com um subconjunto de vértices, conectar um novo vértice `u` à `T` pode ser feito por qualquer aresta que liga `u` à um vértice `v` em `T`, pois os demais vértices de `T` também ficarão conectados a `u` após a adição da aresta `(u, v)`. E todos os vértices de `T` já estão conectados entre si, então você pode abstrair essas conexões e focar apenas nas que faltam.

Comment: Uma correção. Você precisa encontrar uma floresta usando as arestas em `A` e não uma árvore. Isso significa que pode ser um conjunto de árvores (e, mais formalmente, significa que basta o grafo ser acíclico, mas não necessariamente conexo). Para isso, basta aplicar o `Algoritmo de Kruskal` **sem ordenação**. Se no final o algoritmo encontrar apenas uma árvore, você chama a recursão para o conjunto `A`, se encontrar mais de uma árvore, você considera cada árvore como um nó e chama para `B`. Tem várias implementações do Kruskal na internet, segue [uma](http://www.codcad.com/lesson/44).

Comment: Então seu algoritmo ficaria mais ou menos assim: [pseudocodigo1](https://gist.github.com/mauroberto/a54a3dd226d80b4cd2eb7cd264e4c178) e [pseudocodigo2](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wchnqjjjdptv).

Comment: Tentarei uma implementação e postarei aqui!